# Reading WMS capabilities the right way

Tags: wms, getcapabilities, getmap

I'm a new on GIS, And I'm coding a program that can interact on WMS map, I using the https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control library.

I have two WMS capabilities links.

- https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dop?request=GetCapabilities
- https://geoportal.regionalverband-braunschweig.de/geoserver/rrop08/wms?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0&service=wms

With the first WMS capabilities link, I can load the image right way with config:

- WMS URL: `https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dop?`
- WMS Layer: WMS_NW_DOP
- CRS: EPSG:25832

The Map Can Show Smooth.

But with the second WMS Capabilities, the config I using is

- WMS URL: `https://geoportal.regionalverband-braunschweig.de/geoserver/rrop08/ows?`
- WMS Layer: RROP08 Verkehr Luft
- CRS: EPSG:25832

the image is totally white.

And I found some different between two Capabilities XML. With the second link. The name of layer have space. and it is longer than the first.

And I think that, seem I not understand about the WMS capabilities XML file, so how to read the XML file by the right way?

What is real WMS URL?, What WMS layer should be selected? and more more thing about the XML tag's mean?

Comment: Have you tried loading the WMS in QGIS, or ArcMap? Perhaps you are zoomed in to the wrong location? The *Verkehr Luft* layer seems to have only three features, so they are easy to miss. Could you be more specific about *what* exactly you do not understand about the capabilities document?

Comment: Have you read the WMS specification?

Comment: @IanTurton yes, i didn't read it, cause of i did know how to start. so what is the start point to understand the WMS capabilites file

Comment: @Berend what is real WMS endpoint in the XML file. i found very many link. and the Layer too, i see the layer tag have attribute like: queriable=1 or 0, opaque=1 or 0. that make me confuse

Comment: and the layer name, some kind of WMS capabilities file has space between to words

Comment: You could start here: https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms or more specifically, here: http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416 GetCapabilities is described in chapter 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WMS GetCapabilities response is always an XML file, so the correct way to read it is with an XML parser.

The URL to use as the basis of your GetMap request is given in the response, so with

```
https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dop?request=GetCapabilities
```

Strictly the URL request is incorrect (not standard) it should be at least:

```
https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dop?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&
```

The GetMap request URL is:

```
https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dop?
```

and in:

```
https://geoportal.regionalverband-braunschweig.de/geoserver/rrop08/wms?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0&service=wms
```

again strictly incorrect, should be:

```
https://geoportal.regionalverband-braunschweig.de/geoserver/rrop08/wms?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0&service=WMS&
```

The GetMap request URL is given as:

```
https://geoportal.regionalverband-braunschweig.de/geoserver/rrop08/ows?SERVICE=WMS&
```

The `CRS` elements tell you you which CRS you can use in a request, and the `BoundingBox` elements tell you what the spatial extent of the layer is for the specified CRS.

Your 'white image' is probably correct, that is you've asked for a section of the map that has no data.  As can be seen below, the **RROP08 Verkehr Luft** layer has a lot of no data.

[image: example WMS request]

```
queryable="0"
```

Means that the layer is not queryable, that is you can't do a GetFeatureInfo request at a point location to get more information on the underlying data.

```
queryable="1"
```

Means you can query the underlying data.